# Findbugs in Gradle build fails after upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Error message:

No files to be analyzed

My findbugs configuration is like:

```
tasks.create([ "type" : FindBugs, "dependsOn" : "assemble", "group": "verification", "name": "findbugs"]) {
    classes = files("$projectDir.absolutePath/build/intermediates/classes")

    source = fileTree('src/main/java')
    classpath = files()
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like the class path have changed in AGP 3.2 from `build/intermediates/classes` to `build/intermediates/javac`.

Answer (score 2):

```
task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = true
    classes = files("${project.rootDir}/app/build/intermediates/javac",
            "${project.rootDir}/database/build/intermediates/javac",
            "${project.rootDir}/dataprovider/build/intermediates/javac")
    source = fileTree('app/src/main/java/')
classpath = files()
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the classes path in file findbugs.gradle from `classes = fileTree("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/dev/debug/com/android"`
to `classes = fileTree("$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes/android"`.